# reg ex to replace text or blank between certain words/characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string and I want to modify only certain parts of it.

I want to be replace everything between `[summary]=` and `&` with with my own custom text..

Here's a string example

```
var test = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://whatever&p[summary]=aaa&p[title]=blahblahblah&p[images][0]=test.jpg";
```

and sometimes there is nothing inside of `[summary]=` and `&`

```
var test2 = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://whatever&p[summary]=&p[title]=blahblahblah&p[images][0]=test.jpg";
```

I was thinking something like this but this reg doesn't work

```
alert( test.replace("/^\[summary\]\=(.*)&/", "test") ) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var newValue = "new text here";
test.replace(/(\[summary\]=)[^&]*(&)/, "$1" + newValue + "$2");
```

Let me break down what I did:

- `test.replace( . . . );` - I think you understand this part.   ;)
- `/. . ./` - the regex pattern boundaries . . . notice there are no quotes around it (regex patterns are not strings).  Also note that I did not start the pattern with `^` or end it with `$`, since you are trying to match only a piece of the string, not the entire string.
- `(\[summary\]=)` - This not only matches the summary value that you were looking for, but, because it is in parentheses, it also captures it for use later in the replacement.
- `[^&]*` - This matches any "non-`&`" characters.  It's not in parentheses, because we are replacing, so we don't need to capture the value.
- `(&)` - This matches the `&` character and captures it for use in the replace.
- `"$1" + newValue + "$2"` - This part is the replacement value . . . it wraps the two values captured by the regex pattern (`$1` = "[summary]=" and `$2` = "&") around the new value that you want to insert into the string.

I like capturing the values because it keeps you from having to store a string that matches the value that it's replacing . . . better to just reuse what you matched, in my opinion.

Comment: Haha, sorry about that ^^; Though for me, I try to avoid capturing and backreferencing because this causes a little overhead in memory. Have a lot like that, and your app will slow down!

Comment: same as in jerry's first answer, you should replace the + with a *, else it wont't replace an empty string between summary adn &

Comment: @Jerry - Well hopefully he's not doing TOO many of these.   :D

Comment: @lordvlad - good point . . . updated. I was sort of assuming that the entire parameter would left out if the value was empty, but using `*` would 1) handle if parameter is there, but empty, and 2) certainly wouldn't hurt anything if the parameter wasn't there at all.  Good suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The `^` matches the beginning of a string and hence, you'll get no match at all if none of your strings start with `[smmary]`.

Remove it and convert your `.*` to a negated class to avoid greedy matching and improve performance:

```
/\[summary\]=[^&]*&/
```

Note that you don't need to escape `=` or capture the part to replace.

And replace with `"[summary]=" + text + "&"`. Since you want to have `[summary]=` and `&` in the result but are using it in the replace itself, you need to put it back, otherwise you won't have either `[summary]=` or `&` in the result (they are replaced as well), but only your replacement text.

Note you don't quote the regex:

```
alert( test.replace(/\[summary\]=[^&]*&/, "[summary]=" + text + "&") ) ;
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Unknown008/yPAV5/1/)

---

If you wanted to use capture groups, you could have done it like this:

```
alert( test.replace(/(\[summary\]=)[^&]*(&)/, "$1" + text + "$2") ) ;
```

But it's really not necessary since you already know what the capture groups will contain.

Comment: i was about to write the same. maybe you can add info why he should add "[summary..." to the replace string

Comment: @lordvlad That's a good idea, and yea, I always tend to use `+` more than `*` for some reason ^^;

Comment: Dang, @Jerry . . . you updated yours faster than I could type in mine.  Almost identical final answers.   :)

Comment: great answer but talemyn gave more details/explanations and I had to choose one =(

Comment: @CodeCrack Don't worry, it's okay :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove starting hat-symbol, omit quotes and replace greedy match with ungreedy, smth like this:

```
test.replace(/\[summary\]=(.*?)&/, "test")
```

Comment: @lordvlad sure, cuz its "zero-match"
if you want to save the stuff, you should modify the code to test.replace(/\\[summary\\]=(.*?)&/, "[summary]=test&")

Comment: you can drop the parenthesis around `.*?`, too, they dont do nothing in String.replace

Comment: @lordvlad it doesn't matter there but those can be used as backreference in more comple regex'es, eg: test.replace(/\\[summary\\]=(.*?)&p\\[title\\]=(.*?)&/, "[summary]=$2&p[title]=$1&")

Comment: true. its good to know how it works, though it doesn't apply to the example.

Comment: @lordvlad i think it's good idea to keep parentheses even in simple stuff just to see matching expression clearer